# CSV file sorting based on timestamp is not working in linux when year is changed

Tags: linux

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:22
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Oct 30 2014 03:21
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Nov 30 2014 03:12
data3,Send for Translation To CTM,Nov 30 2014 03:10
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:22
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:20
```

I am trying to sort the file based on the time stamp with this ommand:

```
awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.4rd" }' random.csv
```

This command is sorting properly when year is single, but when the multiple years are present it is putting the older ones first just like below:

```
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:22
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:20
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:22
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Oct 30 2014 03:21
```

I need the file with latest timestamp and year should go down in this order: 2014, 2013, 2012 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Just tell sort to look at the year, too:

```
-k3.8,3.11nr
```

i.e. take the third column, sort numerically based on the substring from the 8th to the 11th character, `r` to reverse the order.

Your real data also contain dates like the following:

```
Dec 5 2013 03:05
```

It makes it impossible to use positions in the string, as the single digit days break them. I'd probably switch to Perl, but you can still try to use `sed` to fix the input:

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\) /  \1 /' a.csv \
    | awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.5,6rn" }'
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to linux and still learning. Are u talking about this change:
awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.8,3.11n" }'

Its not sorting as expected

Comment: @user3884944: If you want to sort by year as primary, put it before the month and day parts.

Comment: I used this command: awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.4rd" }'  but it did not work properly and year is coming in random order. I have shared that sorted csv here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aDLPFJOqw7eFJta0hxa0hTcE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3884944: Do you know that the `NR` part skips the first line (intended to be a header, I'd guess)? I can't access google drive from work.

Comment: yes, this is for header. I need the header in the file which I have sorted. Please check the file which I have shared, when you get some time after your work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, but for large data this is failing and 2013 is sandwiched between 2014s !! When you will see the shared csv on google drive, u will get to know :)

Comment: The problem is some you dates are of the form `Dec 5 2013 03:05`, i.e. the day is single digit. It breaks the positions in the substring. Check the update.